# Problem Using NHibernate Criteria API to Get Specific Results from a Referenced Object

Tags: nhibernate

I have an Class that is named Show one of the properties "Country" is a reference to another table.

Show Class

```
public class Show
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country CountryOrigin { get; set; }
    public virtual string EnglishName { get; set; }
}
```

Country Class

```
public class Country
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have it all mapped and working, but now I am wanting to get more specific results. I have used the criteria api to get all the data and sort it, but now I only want to get shows based on country name. Here is what I thought would work, but apprently doesn't.

```
public IList<Show> AllShowsByCountry(string countryName)
{
    IList<Show> shows;

    shows = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Show))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CountryOrigin.Name", "China" ))
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc("EnglishName"))
        .List<Show>();

    return shows;
}
```

I was thinking that the first part of the restriction might work similar to HQL and you can use objects.

**1) The question I guess is am I mis-understanding how HQL works or criteria or both?

2) Also how would you do this properly using criteria?**

**Update**
Here is the error I am getting

```
could not resolve property: CountryOrigin.Name of: Entities.Show
```

Comment: That can be useful. I updated the post with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Criteria, use the following:

```
_session.CreateCriteria<Show>()
        .CreateAlias("CountryOrigin", "country")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("country.Name", countryName))
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc("EnglishName"))
        .List<Show>();
```

Of course HQL is easier when you are not constructing a dynamic query (search):

```
_session.CreateQuery(
@"
  from Show
  where CountryOrigin.Name = :countryName
  order by EnglishName
")
.SetParameter("countryName", countryName)
.List<Show>();
```

And Linq always rocks:

```
_session.Query<Show>()
        .Where(s => s.CountryOrigin.Name = countryName)
        .OrderBy(s => EnglishName)
        .ToList();
```

(`.Query` is for NH 3.x; for 2.x use `.Linq`)

Comment: awesome thank you. I am going to have to read up on CreateAlias.